# parse(Float64,trip)--error:cannot parse trip as Float64

Tags: parsing, julia

The code that I use:

```
for trip in df[:Polyline]
      trip ＝ parse(Float64,trip)  |＞ eval
end
```

The error I get:

> error:cannot parse trip as Float64

trip is a string like `[[-8.764913,6.461675],[7.461345,9.754319]]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a minimal working example in your question (try to edit it!). However this is what I understand that you need.

Suppose you have a `String`:

```
trip = "[[-8.7,6.4],[7.4,9.7],[3.4,2.1]]"
```

Use `JSON.jl` package to parse it:

```
julia> using JSON

julia> JSON.parse(trip)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 Any[-8.7, 6.4]
 Any[7.4, 9.7]
 Any[3.4, 2.1]
```

You might prefer to have an `Array` of `Float64`s instead:

```
julia> Vector{Float64}.(JSON.parse(trip))
3-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [-8.7, 6.4]
 [7.4, 9.7]
 [3.4, 2.1]
```